# Error using Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to use Cloud Storage with App Engine.  But I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sigmar-notes1/1.389052547617375726/main.py", line 47, in post
    real_path = os.path.join('/', bucket_name, user.user_id(), file_name)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 75, in join
    if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I'm new to App Engine and I'm using code from "Python for google App Engine" by Massimiliano Pippi.  Here is the code I'm using.

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        template_context = {}

        if user is not None:
            logout_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            template_context = {
                'user': user.nickname(),
                'logout_url': logout_url,
            }
            template = jinja_env.get_template('main.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(template_context))

        else:
            login_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            self.redirect(login_url)

    def post(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user is None:
            self.error(401)

        bucket_name = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()
        uploaded_file = self.request.POST.get('uploaded_file')
        file_name = getattr(uploaded_file, 'filename', None)
        file_content = getattr(uploaded_file, 'file', None)
        real_path = ''
        if file_name and file_content:
            content_t = mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)[0]
            real_path = os.path.join('/', bucket_name, user.user_id(), file_name)

            with cloudstorage.open(real_path, 'w', content_type=content_t) as f:
                f.write(file_content.read())

        self._create_note(user, file_name)

        logut_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        template_context = {
            'user': user.nickname(),
            'logout_url': logut_url,
            'note_title': self.request.get('title'),
            'note_content': self.request.get('content'),
        }
        self.response.out.write(self._render_template('main.html', template_context))

    def _render_template(self, template_name, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}

        user = users.get_current_user()
        ancestor_key = ndb.Key("User", user.nickname())
        gry = Note.owner_query(ancestor_key)
        context['notes'] = gry.fetch()

        template = jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
        return template.render(context)

    @ndb.transactional
    def _create_note(self, user, file_name):
        note = Note(parent=ndb.Key("User", user.nickname()), title=self.request.get('title'), content=self.request.get('content'))
        note.put() 

        item_titles = self.request.get('checklist_items').split(',')
        for item_title in item_titles:
            item = CheckListItem(parent=note.key, title=item_title)
            item.put()
            note.checklist_items.append(item.key)

        if file_name:
            note.files.append(file_name)

        note.put()
```

Comment: Just a comment on the question, there is too much code here that really isn't relevant to the question.  You should try to reduce the code to a minimal set that exhibits the problem. This will also help with your own debugging.

Answer (score 1):

One of your arguments to the `os.path.join` call is `None`:

```
real_path = os.path.join('/', bucket_name, user.user_id(), file_name)
```

Comment: My bet would be `file_name` because it is acquired via `getattr(uploaded_file, 'filename', None)`.

Comment: It's actually bucket_name.  I've activated the Cloud Storage API but there does not seem to be a default bucket.  Can not for the life of me find any way to find the default bucket or create one.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the default bucket had not been created.  I had to use the old app engine console to create it.  Here is a link to the [solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/QotaPSdq4ro)